# how can I reset an iOS app to it's initial state when the user logs out

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a simple way for a user to restore an iOS app to it's original state on the device when the user signs out of the app?

I am currently manually deleting all the coreData objects and dismissing all viewControllers and clearing NSUserDefaults.

What I want to achieve is exactly the app state when the user first downloads and interacts with it.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: If you mean "restore defaults" by also restoring push auth user answer, location auth user answer, the answer is NO. It is handled by iOS. If you want just to clear all data, I think your approach is correct, but AFAIK there is no `clear` method to wizard all the work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic step to accomplish what you want , you have to manually clear any content that you have set , also you can search for the optimum way to do that for example instead of deleting the userdefauts key by key you can delete all the content with 1 line